# convert Java to javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

Someone can help me,i have stuck here,i have code java like this:

```
List<Object> lstObject = new ArrayList<>();
Object o = lstObject.get(0);
```

and now im confiuse how to change in the code javascript.
i hope some one can answer my question,and explain the logic.

thanks,

Comment: `var lstObject = []; var o = lstObject[0];`

Comment: How familiar are you with javascript code? That may help us answer a more fundamental and generic question.

Comment: What are you confused about? We can't read your mind, and it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I do not understand by too javascript method , but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring a new empty array

```
var lstObject = [];
```

access the array

```
var o = listObject[0];
```

These are the basics of JS. Please read about
[JavaScript Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)